# Why does this sympy function return an empty list as an answer?

Tags: python, list, sympy, solver, algebra

I am trying to solve this equation for x with python.

```
x - 1 = 99
```

I have this code, which should solve this.

This code is the minimum code I could find to reproduce the issue.

```
from sympy import Symbol,solve
x = Symbol('x',real=True)
eq = x-1==99
answer = solve(eq,x)
print(answer)
```

When I run the code, it returns this.

```
[]
```

The answer I am looking for is 100.

There are no error messages, and I have x set as a real number, so I do not understand why it returns this.

Could someone help?

Comment: You probably want `x = Symbol('x', real = True)` (one equal sign, not two).

Comment: I tried that, but it still has the same problem.

Comment: The `sympy` gotcha's warn about using the `==`.  That's a python operator, not a sympy operator.

Comment: [sympy gotchas about equations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs).  You need `Eq(lhs, rhs)` instead of `lhs == rhs` to represent an equation in sympy.  Older, still supported, code uses `lhs - rhs` and supposes equating with zero.  The notation with `Eq(lhs,rhs)` is preferred for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with SymPy, but just looking at the docs on [solving algebraic equations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#algebraic-equations), it says *"We suppose all equations are equaled to 0"*. Also, if you print `eq` from your code, you'll see that it's `False`, not an equation.

So simply move the 99 to the other side of the equals sign:

```
eq = x-1 - 99
```

Answer: `[100]`

Comment: That solved it! Although, I want to be able to put in equations like so: x-20 = 10. Do you know how I can make an equation equal to a number other than 0?

Comment: @Ryan Yeah, you just need to subtract like I wrote: `x-20 - 10`. IDK if SymPy has anything built-in to do that automatically, but if you're say, reading from a text file, it might be enough to just replace any occurrence of an `'='` with `'-'`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help?

```
from sympy import solveset
from sympy import Symbol, Eq
x = Symbol('x')
solveset(Eq(x-1, 99), x)
```